# Django query over multiple tables

Tags: python, django

I got so much trouble forming the right query to get my result...

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class GeoCatch(models.Model):
    user_me = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='me')
    user_he = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='he')
    permission_he = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    permission_me = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**The query I need:**

get names in djangos User table of various user_he which have user_me = 1 and have permission_he = True and permission_me= True

This and a couple other querys were not successful...

```
get_friends =  User.objects.values_list('username').filter(geoCatch__user_me=id)/
.filter(permission_he = True).filter(permission_me= True)
```

Gives me Error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'geoCatch' into field.

Answer (score 2):

```
friends = GeoCatch.objects.filter(user_me=User.objects.get(pk=id)) \
                    .filter(permission_me=True) \
                    .filter(permission_he=True).user_he_set.all()
```

Comment: okay sorry: i set id to 1 and now it gives me : AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'he_set'

Answer (score 1):

```
# id is an id of a user object
get_friends =  User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)\
    .filter(me__user_me__id=id, me__permission_he = True, me__permission_me= True)
```

Comment: this works! if id is set by the user object...sorry...hard to understand especially the __me stuff...

Comment: hmm it just gives me the username of the id so many times like it has found matching permission_he and permission_me...